# What type of distribution is $f(x; \theta)=\theta e^{-x}+2(1-\theta)e^{-2x}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Does anyone know what type of distribution this is?

$$f(x;\theta)=\theta e^{-x}+ 2(1-\theta)e^{-2x}$$

Where $\theta \in [0,1]$ and for $x \ge 0$.

I am trying to show that $f(x;\theta)$ is a density function.

Comment: Unless you restrict the value of $x$ in some way this clearly isn't a density function as it's unbounded for $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution

Comment: Any convex combination of density functions is a density function.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It is a [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) (sum of nonnegative weights is $1$) of two [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) densities. For fixed $\theta$, one needs to check that $f(x;\theta ) >0$ for all $x$ and that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x; \theta) dx = 1$

Answer (score 1):

A density function $f:\mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{R}$ must satisfy two properties:

1: $f(x)\geq 0 ~ \forall x\in\mathcal{X}$

2: $\int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x)\mathrm{d}x=1$.

Let's now investigate $g(x|\theta)=\theta e^{-x} + 2(1-\theta)e^{-2x}$.
Well, if $\theta \in [0,1]$, it's pretty clear $g(x|\theta) \geq 0$.
And,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\theta e^{-x} + 2(1-\theta)e^{-2x} ~\mathrm{d}x=(-\theta e^{-x} + (-1/2)\cdot 2(1-\theta)e^{-2x})\bigg|^{\infty}_{0}$$
$$=(-\theta e^{-x} + (\theta-1)e^{-2x})\bigg|^{\infty}_{0}$$
$$=-\theta(0-1)+(\theta-1)(0-1)$$
$$=\theta+1-\theta=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know what type of distribution this is?

It's a

[Hyperexponential Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperexponential_distribution)